# How to look up instance names of publishers and subscribers in distribution database

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am writing a program using RedGate SQL Compare that syncs data between nodes in a transactional replication topology. In cases where there are more than 2 nodes, I need an automated way of creating pairings of SQL instance/database name so that I can sync all the links in the tree.

I believe this information is stored in the distribution database. I have found tables that contain the names of the publication database and subscription database (MSsubscriptions).

However, although publisher_id and subscriber_id are listed as fields, I don't see how I can use that to get the names of the SQL instances.

The MSsubscriber_info in the distribution database contains the SQL instance names of the publishers, but there is no ID column.

Does anyone know how I can obtain the publisher matched with the publication database? I would appreciate any advice anyone can give. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you're looking for is in `master.sys.servers`

So you'd join the publisher_id and subscriber_id from the `MSsubscriptions` on `server_id` in the `servers` table. This should be a good starting point for you (assuming SQL Server 2005 or greater)

```
select distinct pub.name, sub.name
    from master.sys.servers pub
        join distribution.dbo.MSsubscriptions s
            on s.publisher_id = pub.server_id
        join master.sys.servers sub
            on s.subscriber_id = sub.server_id;
```

Comment: This is great. I wouldn't have thought to look in the master database. Thanks!

Comment: I'll just add that you can reference sys.servers from anywhere, not just master.

Comment: This does'nt work for sql server 2005 ,it throws an error `"Invalid object name 'distribution.dbo.MSsubscriptions'."`